# Scala cannot resolve constructor

Tags: java, scala, constructor

I'm leveraging the interoperability between Scala and Java and have the below code that uses Scala, to instantiate a class in the same project that was written in Java. The `CommandExecutor` parameter is inherited from a parent class.

```
class IdmIdentityServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl with IdmIdentityService {
    override def createNativeUserQuery: NativeUserQuery = {
        new NativeUserQueryImpl(commandExecutor)
      }
}
```

I get an error, in instantiating `NativeUserQueryImpl` that says `cannot resolve constructor`

`NativeUserQueryImpl` was written in Java, but I've been reading about the interoperability between Java and Scala and feel like it should work.

This is the `NativeUserQueryImpl` class, which takes in that `CommandExecutor` type in one of it's constructors. The class comes from the flowable-engine library.

```
public class NativeUserQueryImpl extends AbstractNativeQuery<NativeUserQuery, User> implements NativeUserQuery {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public NativeUserQueryImpl(CommandContext commandContext) {
    super(commandContext);
  }

  public NativeUserQueryImpl(CommandExecutor commandExecutor) {
    super(commandExecutor);
  }

  // results ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  public List<User> executeList(CommandContext commandContext, Map<String, Object> parameterMap, int firstResult, int maxResults) {
    return commandContext.getUserEntityManager().findUsersByNativeQuery(parameterMap, firstResult, maxResults);
  }

  public long executeCount(CommandContext commandContext, Map<String, Object> parameterMap) {
    return commandContext.getUserEntityManager().findUserCountByNativeQuery(parameterMap);
  }

}
```

EDIT:

Full error

```
Error:(31, 5) overloaded method constructor NativeUserQueryImpl with alternatives:
  (x$1: org.flowable.idm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutor)org.flowable.idm.engine.impl.NativeUserQueryImpl <and>
  (x$1: org.flowable.idm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext)org.flowable.idm.engine.impl.NativeUserQueryImpl
 cannot be applied to (org.flowable.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutor)
    new NativeUserQueryImpl(commandExecutor)
```

Comment: Where is `commandExecutor` defined?

Comment: @nmat in the same project

Comment: It's inherited from a parent class. I'm adding the full class signature that this is contained in. It is in `ServiceImpl`

Comment: Looks like it should work. Can you post the full output of the compiler error?

Comment: It's just exactly that `cannot resolve constructor`

Comment: The full output shows type definitions about what was expected and what you have.

Comment: posted in edit in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the full error posted in the original question, it appears that the `CommandExecutor` that is inherited from the parent class `ServiceImpl` has two different versions in the library

`org.flowable.idm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutor` and
`org.flowable.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutor` where the subtle difference is that one is from an `idm` package and one is not.

Changing ServiceImpl from the second package to the first, updates the `CommandExecutor` parameter that's being passed in, and fixes the issue.